# User picture preview is not updating with $form_state rebuild

Tags: 7, users

To user profile form I have added a custom submit function.

In that submit function I'm setting the $form_state['rebuild'] value to TRUE.

When I change the user picture and click the save button, it does not update the picture preview.

Then When I reload the page again manually, it updates the picture preview.

What can be the problem and how can I fix this?

I'm using the default picture field. All other fields are updating.